# read and write socket in multithreads

Tags: sockets

Think there are two threads.

Thread A, the GUI main thread, may write data to a socket in callback.
Thread B, the child thread, and blocked on reading from the same socket.

Is this situation safe?

Sorry for my English

Comment: your question is not clear, make it clear and if possible show us your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP sockets are full duplex. You can read from and write to them independently.

Comment: @Wiky Certainly. That's what 'independently' means. There is no interdependence.

Answer (score 0):

man says that there are main thread and child thread... main thread is always having high priority in the operation system.
According to OP. system all threads are 1,2,3,4 levels. According to second level application you can think 12 level at total.
in this state it is 2.level and it is separates 4 other level in itself. 
The main thread on there should be 5.level and the second thread is 6. level. 
Depending on this knowledge maybe persists a deadlock by the time.